# Count visible elements in a scrolled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to calculate how many items are visible (including the last one visible even if there is 10px shown) in a scrollable div to animate it in an AJAX callback transition.
Depending on screens sizes, that can vary and I'm looking for detect that.

The goal is to do something like that (but I don't know the lt(n))

```
$(".box:lt(n)")...
```

**Example:**
— http://jsfiddle.net/gy4uLu7x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do

```
    $(function () {

        var total_width = $(".box").length * $(".box").outerWidth(true);
        $(".scroll").width(total_width);

        var scroll = $('.scroll');
        var viewport_w = scroll.parent().width();
        var box1 = $('.box:first');
        var boxw = box1.outerWidth(true);
        var view_items = Math.ceil(viewport_w/ boxw);
        console.log(boxw, viewport_w, view_items);

     });
```

this code works on the fact that all boxes' (outer)width is equal. It calculates with of the immediate parent of `.scroll` which happens to be the `body` element and checks how many elements will fit into it. It converts the decimal part of the division result into and integer to accommodate for your _ even if there is 10px shown_ requirement. i.e., even 0.1 is converted into a 1.

**Update**
margin collapse won't happen :D

Comment: Yay! thank you :)
Just simplified it in a one line magic variable (adapted for my final code): `var visible_items = Math.ceil($("#photos").width() / $(".thumbnail:first").outerWidth(true));`

Comment: Finally used `Math.ceil(total_width / $(".thumbnail:first").outerWidth(true)) + 1` to be sure to have one more item

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the width of scroll's parent (since this is the "viewport" in this case). Then count the boxes that start at a position less than above calculated width. This will work only in the above mentioned scenario.

```
var parentContainerWidth = $(".scroll").parent().width();
var containedBoxesCount = $('.box').filter(function () {
    return $(this).offset().left <= parentContainerWidth;
}).length;
alert(containedBoxesCount);
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/gy4uLu7x/2/)

Comment: As I as writing this for an Angular project this method is simpler to follow to convert to pure JavaScript.